# How do I load local HTML files using a ListView in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-webview

I've been working on a ListView within Android with a number of items. I'd like each list item to have a corresponding HTML file which loads in a WebView when the list item is clicked. Every list item will have a corresponsing HTML file. The HTML are stored on the device.

To give an idea of the ListView I'm working with I've modified the tutorial here http://javatechig.com/android/android-listview-tutorial/.

I think my problem is I'm used to iOS dev and I'm having a hard time getting my head round it without thinking how I would tackle it in iOS!

Any input appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: These are HTML files on the device or on a server someplace?

Comment: They are local files on the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this in iOS is to use the storyboard template with the list and detail views.

You could do the same in Android with two different activities. You already have one activity with the list. You should add a second activity with just a `WebView` (+ whatever navigation you need surrounding it).

To wire it up you add an `OnItemClickListener` to the listview that fires an intent with the proper activity action.

```
// logic to get the html file goes here
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyWebViewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("fileToShow", theFile);
context.startActivity(i);
```

In your `MyWebViewActivity` you can do this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_with_webview);
    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (null != intent) {
        if (intent.hasExtra("fileToShow")) {
            WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_web_view);
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///" + intent.getExtras().getString("fileToShow");
        }
    }
}
```

You might need to add some more code and layout around this to fit your specific need - but this general approach should work out fine.

Comment: Thanks for this, gave me enough info to point me in right direction.

Answer (score 1):

you can use setOnItemClickListener for listview and pass the html to loadUrl like...

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> element, View arg1, int pos, long arg3){
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.loadUrl(htmladdress);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new activity for the detail view, containing the webview

then, in your listview (master view) onItemClickListener callback get the uri of the file, bundle it as a intent extra and start a new activity

The activity receives the intent, extracts the uri from the extras, and has webview load it

*the local uris are like this* `"file:///" + context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/..."`

so you probably want to set up a database to store the uris, and use a cursor adapter with the listview